# TypeORM - One-To-Many relationship defined in EntitySchema

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with JS and it's docs are super minimal, so I couldn't find the solution for my question over there.
I want to create a one-to-many bi-directional relationship and can't get over the following exception:

`TypeORMError: Entity metadata for Team#groups was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.`

Thats the definition of the two entities (one team might have multiple groups):

```js
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Team',
  tableName: 'team',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'uuid',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
    },
    
  },
  relations: {
    groups: {
      target: 'TeamGroups',
      type: 'one-to-many',
      inverseSide: 'team_id',
    },
  },
})
```

```js
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'TeamsGroups',
  tableName: 'team_group',
  columns: {
    team_id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'uuid',
    },
    group_id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'uuid',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    team_id: {
      target: 'Team',
      type: 'many-to-one',
      joinColumn: true,
    },
  },
})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just curious, why use EntitySchema over the decorators shown on the docs? https://typeorm.io/#/entities

As for the issue, I'm not very familiar with entity schema definitions, but it seems like the key `group` of `relations` should become the name value of the other entity ie `TeamsGroups`. Likewise, I'd match the key name under that relation to the other entity defition name.

Comment: The reason is because im using js and not ts. im not sure if typeORM supports entity decorators.
Regarding your suggestion, I think it 's not the reason, as the key of the relation is the field name that is used to access the relation (teamGroup.team_id should reference the relevant team)

Comment: The entity name is the name you use to access the relation, at least in Typescript with decorators. ie if your entity name was User you would call `getRepository(User)`. You might use the table name using Query Builder, but that's more of a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test but I'm fairly sure it's this, looking at the error & docs:

```
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'Team',
  tableName: 'team',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'uuid',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
    },
    
  },
  relations: {
    TeamGroups: {
      target: 'TeamGroups',
      type: 'one-to-many',
      inverseSide: 'team_id',
    },
  },
})
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
  name: 'TeamsGroups',
  tableName: 'team_group',
  columns: {
    team_id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'uuid',
    },
    group_id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'uuid',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    Team: {
      target: 'Team',
      type: 'many-to-one',
      joinColumn: true,
    },
  },
})
```